# How to apply a warning to several member at once (as all in a group)?

Tags: doxygen

#### The problem

I have a documentation split into two different groups :

- API, intended for regular users, with only safe functions.
- Low level API, intended for more confident users.

I added a `@warning` directive into my Low level API group definition, stating that all member of the group shall be used with care.

I would like this warning to be displayed in the description of every member of the group, so even if users reach member through links and so on, they are warned.

Is there a way to do that without manually adding the `@warning` to every members of the group, and instead apply per group/per file warning ?

#### More information

My version of Doxygen is 1.8.17, however I should be able to upgrade it if required.
I can edit all files of the project, as well as the Doxygen configuration file.

#### Example of wanted behavior

I want to achieve following behavior :

```c
/** @addtogroup low_level_api

  @warning This is a warning I want to display in every member of the group
  @{
*/

/** @brief some function of my example
    @warning This is a warning I want to display in every member of the group
*/
void some_group_member()

/** @brief another function of my example
    @warning This is a warning I want to display in every member of the group
*/
void some_group_member()

/**
@}
*/
```

Without needing to copy-paste the warning in every member of the group, as an hypothetical :

```c
/** @addtogroup low_level_api

  @warning_to_all This is a warning I want to display in every member of the group
  @{
*/

/** @brief some function of my example
*/
void some_group_member()

/** @brief another function of my example
*/
void some_group_member()

/**
@}
*/
```

Of course, `@warning_to_all` directive does not exists, so I need to find an equivalent of this, even if it is a more general and "rough" solution than propagating a warning, as for example displaying the group description in every member description.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Can you give a small example (edit into the question).

Comment: @albert Sorry for imprecisions, I added an example. Please let me know in case it is insufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no real grouping in the sense as OP wants of warnings (as far as I know. A solution might be to use the `\snippet{doc}` command like:

```
/** @addtogroup low_level_api

  \snippet{doc} this snip
  @{
*/

/** @brief some function of my example
    \snippet{doc} this snip
    @warning This is a warning I want to display in every member of the group
*/
void some_group_member();

/** @brief another function of my example
    \snippet{doc} this snip
    @warning This is a warning I want to display in every member of the group
*/
void some_group_member1();

/**
@}
*/

/*
  [snip]
  @warning This is a general warning I want to display in every member of the group
  [snip]
*/
```